# Radius ratio for four packed circles

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Suppose we are given four circles $A,B,C,D$ in the Euclidean plane having radii $r_A,r_B,r_C,r_D$ such that $r_A=r_C,r_B=r_D$ and circles $A,C$ are tangent to each other and to $B,D$ but $B,D$ are only tangent to $A,C$.  Suppose further that a given bounding square $E$ in the plane is tangent to each circle exactly twice.  What is the value of the ratio

$$r_A\over r_B$$

[image: Approximate representation]

Comment: Could you tell us how far you have got, and where you are stuck?

Comment: @OldJohn: I'm not stuck, it's a recreational problem that I just thought up.

Comment: if you wish to recreate, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket#Integral_Apollonian_circle_packings

Comment: @WillJagy: hmm, perhaps this question is equivalent to "Integral Apollonian circle packing defined by circle curvatures of (−1, 2, 2, 3)" then...?

Comment: I don't know, really. I thought you would enjoy the topic. I also do not understand your geometric description. There are a few methods whereby you could draw a picture and post in in your question; that would help. I bought an inexpensive single-page scanner, makes jpegs or pdfs, very useful. Jpegs work better on this site.

Comment: @WillJagy: approximate demonstration picture added.  Since I made the picture, I now know that the answer is no, this is not equivalent to the "Integral Apollonian..." as in my earlier comment since the outermost edges of $A,B,C,D$ are not simultaneously tangent to any bounding circle.

Comment: I see. Very different from the Apollonian thing. This should be solvable. $r_A$ is easy enough. $r_D$ may be a mess but you should at least be able to get it as a root of some polynomial. Dentist appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using alternate diagonals, it is possible to identify the following:

The center of $A(C)$ is $\sqrt{2r_A^2}$ distant from the closest corner of $E$, similarly for $B(D)$, and the distance from the center of $A$ to $C$ is simply $r_A+r_C=2r_A$, so we have diagonal length $d=2\sqrt2r_A+2r_A$.  It is possible to arrive at a similar expression for the other diagonal, except that we must get a good value for the distance between the centers of $B$ and $D$.  Since the four circle centers form a rhombus, the alternate centers cross perpendicularly, so we have $\sqrt{(r_A+r_B)^2-r_A^2}=\sqrt{r_B^2+2r_Ar_B}$ as the distance between centers of $B$ and $D$.  Then we have alternate diagonal length

$$d=2\sqrt2r_B+2\sqrt{r_B^2+2r_Ar_B}=2\sqrt2r_A+2r_A$$

Rearranging, squaring and dividing by $r_A^2$ yields

$${r_B^2\over r_A^2}-2(\sqrt2+3){r_B\over r_A}+(1+\sqrt 2)^2=0$$

This quadratic yields

$${r_B\over r_A}=\sqrt2+3\pm\sqrt{4\sqrt2+8}\approx 0.718695432327948\dots$$

It is certainly the case that the negative branch is appropriate since $r_B\le r_A$ under the conditions and picture shown.  Then the original requested ratio has value

$${r_A\over r_B}=\frac 1{\sqrt2+3-2\sqrt{\sqrt2+2}}$$

which does not appear to look any better upon conjugate multiplication and simplification.